# How do I post messages to arbitrary channels in Slack using the API?

Tags: slack-api

I have a few systems where I would like to take some data and post it to arbitrary channels in our Slack instance. I would like to not have to create a separate webhook URL for every channel because I don't know beforehand where those messages might need to go. There appears to be conflicting documentation on Slack's web site. There is an example of: `curl -X POST \
--data-urlencode 'payload={"text": "This is posted to #general and comes from *monkey-bot*.", "channel": "#general", "link_names": 1, "username": "monkey-bot", "icon_emoji": ":monkey_face:"}' \
https://hooks.slack.com/services/T00000000/B00000000/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`
 which contains a "channel" key, but then above that it says `You cannot override the default username, icon, or channel for incoming webhooks attached to Slack apps. Instead, these values will stubbornly inherit from the associated Slack app configuration.`

I believe that the incoming Webhook approach is what should be taken, particularly since I want the enhanced formatting capabilities that that provides, but I'll admit, I'm a little confused on all of the different programmatic ways to interact with Slack.

Am I missing something? Is there another way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the Web API is the way to go. It does allow for the enhanced formatting and can post to arbitrary channels.